# Unable to open jmx file in Jmeter 5.4.2

Tags: jmeter

When i try to open the jmx file in jmeter5.4.2 I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'D:\Jmeter_Script\CloudBLM_v2\Jmeter\loadscript\CloudBLM_loadscript.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: com.tag.jmeter.ext.config.PropertyReader

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:66)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/com.tag.jmeter.ext.config.PropertyReader
line number         : 70
version             : 5.4.2
```

Comment: Can you install the plugins manager, restart the JMeter and open the JMX? Most probably, Jmeter will prompt you to install the missing plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your JMeter installation doesn't have (at least) one plugin installed, it seems to be [Property File Reader](https://www.vinsguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/)

Download the [plugin](https://www.vinsguru.com/download/87/), it's a .zip archive which contains the .jar file implementing the plugin and copy the .jar file to "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation.

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the plugin, you should be able to open the .jmx test plan after the restart.

In general I don't fully understand why does the plugin even exist, the functionality to read external property files is built into JMeter, you can pass the properties file via [`-q` command line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

```
jmeter -q /path/to/your/file.properties
```

or just copy the properties to [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) and JMeter will pick them up automatically.